# Why does order of parameters matter?

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with functional programming and noticed that when I put the function before the other parameters my functions would no longer work, why is this?

**Works**

```
function forEach(array, action){
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
    action(array[i]);}
}

forEach(["bbq","is","not","phoot"],alert);
```

**Does not work**

```
function forEach(action, array){
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
    action(array[i]);}
}

forEach(["bbq","is","not","phoot"],alert);
```

Comment: Because you're calling it with the arguments in the same order

Comment: If you change the order of the parameters in the function declaration to need to change the order of the parameters at the call site as well.

Comment: What? You've change the order of parameters in the function declaration but not in the function call. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: The parameters describe what was passed in that order, so in the second case alert is the array.

Comment: A language implementation doesn't read the names of your parameters, decipher their english meaning, and assign arguments passed as it sees fit.

Answer (score 1):

The order of parameters matters because the function can't guess which parameter is the array and which one is the action.

You could make the function a bit smarter by making the decision based on the type of the parameters. For example:

```
function forEach() {
    var array = typeof arguments[0] === 'function' ? arguments[1] : arguments[0];
    var action = typeof arguments[0] === 'function' ? arguments[0] : arguments[1];

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length;i++) {
       action(array[i]);
    }
}
```

It handles both cases:

```
forEach(["bbq","is","not","phoot"], alert);
forEach(alert, ["bbq","is","not","phoot"]);
```

See it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdjz2/). Please note that this code is error-prone, it's just for demonstration purposes.